# Is there a way to prevent CakePHP to cascade delete the associated belongsToMany relation

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

I use CakePHP 4 with a plugin called softdelete trait (the forked version for cake 4).

I have a simple many-to-many relation between virtual classrooms and learners.
Furthermore, I made a pivot table called learners_virtual_rooms to link the two.

Now when I edit my classroom, I can add and remove learners.

The issue comes when I try to delete the classroom while there are still learners linked :
The room is soft deleted, the rows in the pivot table are deleted, so far so good,
and then my learners are deleted too !
(at least try to be deleted because cake targets a column that doesn't exist in the learners table : virtual_room_id)

I tried using dependent options on my relations, removing the softdelete plugin, using hasMany relations to no avail.

Next is my code, feel free to ask more if it's not enough.

**The virtual_rooms table**

```
class VirtualRoomsTable extends Table
{
    use SoftDeleteTrait;

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('virtual_rooms');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        //[...]

        $this->belongsToMany('Learners');
        
        //[...]

    }
//[...]
}
```

**The learners table**

```
class LearnersTable extends Table
{
    use SoftDeleteTrait;

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('learners');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        
     //   [...]

        $this->belongsToMany('VirtualRooms');

  //      [...]
    }
//[...]
}
```

**The delete method in my controller**

```
    public function delete(string $virtual_room_id): Response
    {
        Assert::true($this->request->is(['delete', 'post']), __('Méthode http incorecte'));
        $virtual_room = $this->VirtualRooms->get($virtual_room_id);

        if ($this->VirtualRooms->delete($virtual_room)) {
            return $this->setJsonResponse([
                'message' => __('Classe virtuelle supprimée avec succès'),
                'success' => true,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->setJsonResponse([
            'message' => __('La classe virtuelle n\'a pas pu être supprimée'),
            'errors' => $virtual_room,
            'validationErrors' => $virtual_room->getErrors(),
            'success' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

No file for the pivot table.

The stacktrace of the error look like that :

- Cake\Database\Query->execute
  ROOT\vendor\salines\cakephp4-soft-delete\src\Model\Table\SoftDeleteTrait.php:120
- App\Model\Table\LearnersTable->deleteAll
  CORE\src\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany.php:617
- Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany->cascadeDelete
  CORE\src\ORM\AssociationCollection.php:343
- Cake\ORM\AssociationCollection->cascadeDelete
  ROOT\vendor\salines\cakephp4-soft-delete\src\Model\Table\SoftDeleteTrait.php:84
- App\Model\Table\VirtualRoomsTable->_processDelete
  CORE\src\ORM\Table.php:2281

The queries that cause the exception :

This one is ok

```
DELETE FROM 
  learners_virtual_rooms 
WHERE 
  virtual_room_id = 31
```

This one is the culprit

```
UPDATE 
  learners 
SET 
  deleted = '2021-03-23 14:44:03' 
WHERE 
  virtual_room_id = '31'
```

debug($this->VirtualRooms->Learners->junction()) :

```
APP/Controller\Api\VirtualRoomsController.php (line 119)
object(Cake\ORM\Table) id:0 {
'registryAlias' => 'LearnersVirtualRooms' 
'table' => 'learners_virtual_rooms' 
'alias' => 'LearnersVirtualRooms' 
'entityClass' => 'Cake\ORM\Entity'
'associations' => [
(int) 0 => 'Learners', (int) 1 => 'VirtualRooms',
]
```

I'm thinking of removing by hand all the learners before deleting the classroom, is it the only way ?

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: By default CakePHP's cascading delete feature for `belongsToMany` associations will only delete join table entries, and nothing beyond that. It couldn't go any further even if it wanted to, as the `belongsTo` associations that connect to your target table do not implement cascading delete operations. For starters I would suggest that you check the stracktrace that belongs to the error that you are receiving, to figure from where the delete operation on your learners table is actually being triggered.

Comment: I added the stacktrace and the queries that triggers the error, if by default belongsTo associations don't go beyond the join table, something is very wrong here. BelongsToMany->cascadeDelete is called and directly after LearnersTable->deleteAll which is not what I want and asked.

Comment: There's definitely something wrong, `deleteAll()` should be called on the join table there, not the target table. Try this in your controller, what does it show: `debug($this->VirtualRooms->Learners->junction())`?

Comment: I added the part of  ```debug($this->VirtualRooms->Learners->junction())``` that's interesting, nothing out of the ordinary I'd say

Comment: That looks correct. And you receive the same error when you remove the soft delete plugin from all tables?

Comment: Yes, same behavior

Comment: That's weird. I can't really do much more from here, I can only suggest that you [**dig into `\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany::cascadeDelete()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.2.4/src/ORM/Association/BelongsToMany.php#L584-L620) and debug if and why `$table` is your target table table instead of the junction table, you'll have to follow the `$this->junction()` call in there then.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll look into it and come back if I find something.